# Finding the right interval

Tags: calculus, functions, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, interval-arithmetic

I have this question but I'm not really sure what the answer is. It says for $1$ week so does it mean the interval is $0 \leq x\leq7$? When I drew the graph $7$ had the lowest $y$ value, does it mean it is the warmest at $7$? I was wondering if you could help me out.

Question:
the thickness of the ice on a lake for one week is modeled by the function:
$$T(d)=-0.1d^3+1.2d^2-4.4d+14.8$$
where $T$ is the thickness in cm and $d$ is the number of days after December $31$st.
a) when does the warmest day occur during this week? determine the average rate of change in a short interval near the point you chose.

Comment: By "warmest day", they probably do, indeed, mean you want to minimize T. However, I am not sure whether you should consider the interval $[0, 6]$ or the interval $[1, 7]$ - I would say the latter, assuming the year begins on a Monday.